# How can you get ref's with dynamic uri's with $firebaseRefProvider?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

With `$firebaseRefProvider` is used to promote DI in angular for testing. Trying to use in an app to inject a reference based on the currentUser.

There is no documentation on it. Did find a video on [Firebase Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9HhM8CugHoE) channel. For example:

```
var config = {
    apiKey: 'somekey',
    authDomain: 'someAuthDomain',
    databaseURL: 'https://some-domain.firebaseio.com',

angular.module('app').config(function($firebaseRefProvider) {
    $firebaseRefProvider.registerUrl({
        default: config.databaseURL,
        peopleRef: `${config.databaseURL}/people`
```

So I wanted to use it to update a user feed like so:

```
    ...
     .service('FbArrayService', ($firebaseRef, $firebaseArray, $firebaseAuth)  => {
        var vm = this
        vm.currentUser = $firebaseAuth.$getAuth();
        vm.currentUserFeed = $firebaseArray($firebaseRef.child(`feeds/${vm.currentUser}`));
        })
       .controller('MyController', (FbArrayService) => {
       var userfeed = FbArrayService.currentUserFeed; 
       ... 
})
```

**Problem**: Getting error --

```
child is not a method of $firebaseRef provider
```

Isn't there a way to get a child ref of the root ref from the ref provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after playing around with it for a while I finally realized that is plain js logic that I was overlooking. But you never know within an api.

```
 vm.currentUserFeed = $firebaseArray($firebaseRef.child(`feeds/${vm.currentUser}`));
```

needs have the **.default** (which actually references the root) so the child method can be used.

```
 vm.currentUserFeed = $firebaseArray($firebaseRef.default.child.(`feeds/${vm.currentUser}`));
```

I guess I thought the .default property was automatically given to the base provider

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('feeds/${vm.currentUser}');

$firebaseArray(ref);
```

Comment: Yes I know that way. Thanks. Trying to inject it (angular's way to make testing easier ). By not relying on outside sources within the service or controller that you are trying to test. Check DI  dependency injection.  Or check that video link above. cheers.